# Optimization of nested entities in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, optimization

I'm developing an application where users can design custom forms for data input.

I'd like to know how to load data with nhibernate with as few database requests as possible?

### My Domain Model:

They are four entities;

**FormProfile** - *Title, description, creation date etc.*
**FieldGroup** -*Fieldsets with title and other properties*
**FormField** -*Each "row" in the fieldgroup, ex "Zip & Area"*
**FieldProperty** -*Each input/select/radiobutton on the FormField row. Ex. Textboxes for Zip & Area*

A form structure usually looks something like this:

- FormProfile

  - FieldGroup

    - FormField

      - FieldProperty

  - FieldGroup

    - FormField

      - FieldProperty
      - FieldProperty

What is the best way to load a FormProfile with all child items avoiding as many roundtrips to db as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way IMO is to use the `batch-size` attribute in your collections.

I'm going to assume your **FormProfile** class has a **FieldGroups** collection, which have a **FormFields** collection, which have a **FieldProperties** collection.

Set `batch-size` to a reasonable number (say, 20), which will be the `number of collections` to query at once.

This way, when you get and navigate a FormProfile, you'll have just 3 additional queries (one for each collection type). These queries are small and fast (they hit only one table each, and will use an index seek on the FK if you defined one), which is usually better than having a big, denormalized query.

You can also enable second-level caching on the entities and collections, for even better performance.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the kind of solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Two methods spring to mind:

- Use cacheing, so you only load the objects the first time they are
  requested
- Use eager fetching, which will create SQL statements that
  use outer joins to pull children records in the same query as their
  parent.

NHibernate provides a second level cache, which is persistant per SessionFactory (unlike the regular first level cache, which is only persistant per Session).

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using caching and eager fetching but I'd like to know if you can optimize the nhibernate mapping in some clever way to load more data at once. With MulitQuery or such?